# gmail API Users.messages: list is not getting replies

Tags: google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-apis-explorer

If I make a request to the gmail API for Users.messages.list it will return 100 of the newest messages.

If I make another request, 1 minute later and there are no new emails it will return the same 100 most recent messages.

If I make a third request, 2 minutes after the original and there is a reply to one of the 100 most recent messages it will still return the 100 most recent messages.

The problem with this is the it only returns the message id and thread id, not if there is a new reply or not.  That would mean that I would have to check every message that I have locally stored, or every one of the 100 returned messages just to know if there was a reply to it or not.

The way that works, you couldn't "check" your email via the api because if you had stored 10000 messages and you were checking replies on all of them you would use up your entire API "number of requests" allocation in a single day!

What's wrong with you Google?

Sure I could use pop3 or imap but why when I could just use something like /list_recent?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: The issue was not the API, Users.messages.list does return replies.

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely take a look at this part of the Gmail API documentation: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/guides/push

Basically, it explains you how you can setup a "watch" over a Gmail account and receive notifications (new e-mail, deleted e-mail, labels added...) through Pub/Sub, the messaging queue protocol from Google.

The notifications will contain an `historyId`, which is a kind of milestone in the Gmail account. Using the [`/history` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list), you'll then get the e-mails that were added and/or deleted since this history point. You have to store the latest `historyId` you handled somewhere in your app, so that you can query the right changes (and not miss anything) on the next notification.

If you don't need to react to changes in real-time, maybe you can call the `/history` endpoint periodically, but it will definitely be less efficient at scale.

It takes a bit of work to get this working but at the end of the day you get a very efficient system able to react about changes in real-time.

Comment: This is a good explanation.

Rather that using Pub/Sub first, I am going to set up the polling with [`/history` endpoint](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/history/list)]



I think it's important to note that you need to get the first set of messages with messages.list then use the most recent historyId (which you can only get through messages.get and the message ids from messages.list) to get the messages which are newer than that historyId.

Comment: I am also not understanding why messages.list wouldn't accept a sinceHistoryId argument, why should there be an entire endpoint for the same call with a different sorting parameter?

Comment: Well, I think that philosophically, `/list` is there, well, to list messages that actually exist. While `/history` can give you messages that were deleted and labels that were added/deleted on a message.

Comment: But you should still be able to order ones that actually exist by using an argument or parameter passed to /list